# How to restrict user to only using letters in typing their name in Processing?

Tags: string, if-statement, processing

I have only taken one coding class so I am still pretty new. The title is pretty much it. The user types their name at the beginning of my game using

```
 if (scr.showingTitleScreen()==true && keyCode!=ENTER) {
    name+=key;
  }
```

How do I make it so that they can only type letters and no other characters? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll like this:

```
string myName = "";

void keyTyped() {
  // The variable "key" always contains the value 
  // of the most recent key pressed.
  if ((key >= 'A' && key <= 'z') || key == ' ') {
    myName += key;
    // Write the letter to the console
    println(key);
  }
}
```

This works because [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/) have "number equivalents" which starts at 65 for 'A' and go all the way to 172 for 'z'. So basically we're checking if the user used... the alphabet. Or a space in this case. You may want to include the backspace too... 'cause for now they can type but not erase!

[Here's the reference page from processing.org.](https://processing.org/examples/charactersstrings.html) Have fun!